# How to get the value of a JSON element in node js? Unable to parse the value in below code

Tags: json, node.js

Below is the theJson string which I have converted to object by JSON.parse

```
var clientScopeJson={"cl1":{"List":"rwe","urlList":["nclsdlc","alkdcjla"]}};
```

JSON.hasOwnProperty(id) returns as true but JSON.id gives undefined:

```
id = "cl1"
//scope = JSON.parse(clientScopeJson);
console.log(clientScopeJson);
clientId = "cl1";
exists = clientScopeJson.hasOwnProperty(clientId); // This returns as true
console.log(exists);
scopeList = clientScopeJson.clientId;
console.log(scopeList);
```

Comment: please provide with the raw string you are trying to convert to JSON object

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access key that is saved in variable, you can access it like this

```
const clientId = "cl1";
const scopeList = clientScopeJson[clientId];
```

If you try to use it with dot, you are trying to access 'clientId' key.